# What is the purpose of the Discover tab in Kibana 4?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I don’t seem to find it useful — I was expecting Discover to give me some insight into my data, but it appears limited and I am required to have some understanding of the underlying data rather than it presenting items of interest to me without prompt.

What can the Discover tab be used for / why is it useful?

Comment: They are related sure, but they are different questions with what I'm sure are different answers.

Comment: That's fair. Would you recommend merging them all into a single large question? I figured one big question with lots of smaller sub-questions might deter people from providing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It allows you which fields are being sent your indexes, quickly find out distribution of values and create a quick visualization of some field (by clicking on "Visualize").

[image: kibana 4 discover]

After you create some dashboards it doesn't make much sense to use "Discover" as Kibana's home page, because you've probably created much comprehensible visualization of incoming data.